# Accumulo's createtable command gets stuck and does not create a table

Tags: accumulo

I was trying to create a table inside Accumulo using the createtable command and found out that it was getting stuck. I waited for around 20 mins before cancelling the createtable command.

```
createtable test_table
```

I have one master and 2 tablet servers and found out that my master and one of the tablets died. I could not telnet to port 9997 of that particular tablet server and I could not even telnet to port 29999 (master.port.client in accumulo-site.xml). When I saw the tserver logs of the dead server, I saw the following entries.

```
2016-05-10 02:12:07,456 [zookeeper.DistributedWorkQueue] INFO : Got unexpected z
ookeeper event: None for /accumulo/be4f66be-1508-4314-9bff-888b56d9b0ce/recovery
2016-05-10 02:12:23,883 [zookeeper.ZooCache] WARN : Saw (possibly) transient exc
eption communicating with ZooKeeper, will retry
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$SessionExpiredException: KeeperErrorCode =
Session expired for /accumulo/be4f66be-1508-4314-9bff-888b56d9b0ce/tables
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:127)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.getChildren(ZooKeeper.java:1472)
        at org.apache.accumulo.fate.zookeeper.ZooCache$1.run(ZooCache.java:210)
        at org.apache.accumulo.fate.zookeeper.ZooCache.retry(ZooCache.java:162)
        at org.apache.accumulo.fate.zookeeper.ZooCache.getChildren(ZooCache.java
:221)
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.impl.Tables.exists(Tables.java:142)
        at org.apache.accumulo.server.tabletserver.LargestFirstMemoryManager.tab
leExists(LargestFirstMemoryManager.java:149)
        at org.apache.accumulo.server.tabletserver.LargestFirstMemoryManager.get
MemoryManagementActions(LargestFirstMemoryManager.java:175)
        at org.apache.accumulo.tserver.TabletServerResourceManager$MemoryManagem
entFramework.manageMemory(TabletServerResourceManager.java:408)
        at org.apache.accumulo.tserver.TabletServerResourceManager$MemoryManagem
entFramework.access$400(TabletServerResourceManager.java:318)
        at org.apache.accumulo.tserver.TabletServerResourceManager$MemoryManagem
entFramework$2.run(TabletServerResourceManager.java:346)
        at org.apache.accumulo.fate.util.LoggingRunnable.run(LoggingRunnable.jav
a:35)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-05-10 02:12:23,884 [zookeeper.ZooCache] WARN : Saw (possibly) transient exc
eption communicating with ZooKeeper, will retry
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$SessionExpiredException: KeeperErrorCode =
Session expired for /accumulo/be4f66be-1508-4314-9bff-888b56d9b0ce/tables/!0/con
f/table.classpath.context
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:127)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:1045)
        at org.apache.accumulo.fate.zookeeper.ZooCache$2.run(ZooCache.java:264)
        at org.apache.accumulo.fate.zookeeper.ZooCache.retry(ZooCache.java:162)
        at org.apache.accumulo.fate.zookeeper.ZooCache.get(ZooCache.java:289)
        at org.apache.accumulo.fate.zookeeper.ZooCache.get(ZooCache.java:238)
        at org.apache.accumulo.server.conf.ZooCachePropertyAccessor.get(ZooCache
PropertyAccessor.java:117)
        at org.apache.accumulo.server.conf.ZooCachePropertyAccessor.get(ZooCache
PropertyAccessor.java:103)
        at org.apache.accumulo.server.conf.TableConfiguration.get(TableConfigura
tion.java:99)
        at org.apache.accumulo.tserver.constraints.ConstraintChecker.classLoader
Changed(ConstraintChecker.java:93)
        at org.apache.accumulo.tserver.tablet.Tablet.checkConstraints(Tablet.jav
a:1225)
        at org.apache.accumulo.tserver.TabletServer$8.run(TabletServer.java:2848
)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:51
1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.
access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.
run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-05-10 02:12:23,887 [zookeeper.ZooReader] WARN : Saw (possibly) transient ex
ception communicating with ZooKeeper
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$SessionExpiredException: KeeperErrorCode =
Session expired for /accumulo/be4f66be-1508-4314-9bff-888b56d9b0ce/tservers/accu
mulo.tablet.2:9997
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:127)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:1045)
        at org.apache.accumulo.fate.zookeeper.ZooReader.getStatus(ZooReader.java
:132)
        at org.apache.accumulo.fate.zookeeper.ZooLock.process(ZooLock.java:383)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$EventThread.processEvent(ClientCnxn.j
ava:522)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$EventThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:498)
2016-05-10 02:12:24,252 [watcher.MonitorLog4jWatcher] INFO : Changing monitor lo
g4j address to accumulo.master:4560
2016-05-10 02:12:24,252 [watcher.MonitorLog4jWatcher] INFO : Enabled log-forward
ing
```

Even the master server's logs had the same stacktrace. My zookeeper is running.

At first, I thought it was a disk issue. Maybe there was no space. But that was not the case. I ran the fsck on the accumulo instance.volumes and it returned the HEALTHY status.

Does anyone know what exactly happened and if possible, how to avoid it?

EDIT : Even the tracer_accumulo.master.log had the same stacktrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ZooKeeper session expirations occur when a thread inside the ZooKeeper client does not get run within the necessary time (by default, 30s) to maintain the session which is an in-memory state between ZooKeeper client and server. There is no single explanation for this, but many common culprits:

1. JVM garbage collection pauses in the client. Accumulo should log a warning if it experienced a pause.
2. Lack of CPU time. If the host itself is overburdened, Accumulo might not have the cycles to run all of the tasks it needs to in a timely manner.
3. Lack of sockets/filehandles, Accumulo could be trying to connect to ZooKeeper, but be unable to open new connections
4. ZooKeeper might be rate-limiting connections as a denial-of-service prevention. Check the zookeeper logs for errors about dropping/denying new connections from a specific IP, and, if you see these errors, consider increasing `maxClientCnxns` in zoo.cfg.